# install Gtalk on android 3.0 Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, installation, google-talk

IN my application I need to call intent of Gtalk. therefore at first i need to install Gtalk on my emulator to do initial test. But i could not find any apk which successfully  install on Android emulator. I am using Android SDK 3.0 and developing application for Android Tablet.
I have tried following method no one work on emulator.

1).I have got some Apk's like 
TalkProvider.apk
gtalkservicea.pk
Talk.apk

I tried to install them in the order mentioned above, Talkprovider install successfully but when I'm trying to install gtalkservice.apk following error display on the console

```
INSTALLATION_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

Hence I couldn't reach at the point to install Talk.apk.
adb install gtalkservice.apk

2)i the 2nd method got following file by digging on internet (apk and lib file)
libtalk_jni.so
Talk2.apk

so lib and apk files need to push in the emulator using command
adb push libtalk_jni.so /system/lib/ ,
same command for Talk2.apk

How could I get Gtalk on my emulator to call intent of Gtalk from my app. Or could I used any other Messenger which consists of many IM contacts (gtalk, yahoo, msn) like 'FRING', mean I install Fring in my emulator and call intnet of Gtalk to FRING?
the requirement is , in my application gtalk contacts are display and when I click some contact then Gtalk/Fring install in my device open to start chat.

How could I full fill this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on the emulator unless you run a system image with the Google apps installed.  You should use a Google device with the Google apps installed (Motorola Xoom, Galaxy Tab, etc) to test this type of functionality.

Comment: Thanks Nate, so you mean its not possibale on the Emulator and i have to test on device ?

Comment: or how could i do the alternate you told , mean run system image with google apps installed, and what is system image?